# How can i remove garbage values from gettype().name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I using`Gettype().Name` to get my class name. when i execute code its does give me class name but adds garbage value like `SavingsAccount_32335C302A2DED6EFF6B9AFA5B79FC440AFD57B29E5123233712CE7F0C5646BF` as a output.
Same things goes with my chequing account. Any help on just geeting class name like `SavingAccount`

Comment: Depends on what library you're working with. It's actually a proxy class typically used by tools like mocking frameworks and ORMs.

Comment: If you only need it as a string, then split('_')[0]

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger The underscore character is a valid character in class names, so that method might split the class name up.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 0):

EF proxy type suffixes can also be removed using `System.Linq` and `Guid.TryParse`

```
Guid guid;
string typeName = string.Join("_", type.Name.Split('_')
                        .Where(pt => !Guid.TryParseExact(new string(pt.Take(32).ToArray()), "N", out guid)));
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Use

```
 string myType = myClass.GetType().ToString();
 string[] parts = myType.Split('_');
 if(myType.Length>{X}&&parts.Length>0)//add RegEx GUID test to be sure
 {
 string myClassName = "";
 for(int I=0;i<parts.Length-1;i++){
      myClassName+= parts[I];
      if(I<parts.Length-1)
        myClassName+="_";
 }
 }
```

*If 'X' > say 35, this will work on every class less than 35 characters long. Add a GUID test using RegEx if you need to filter out long class names.*

2) Since you have this problem, don't use underscores in your other classes.

3) If the add-on is a GUID (or if it always has the same number of digits), test for length and delete the last X digits if the class name is long and contains an underscore.

4) Use RegEx to test for a guid https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+guid+test&ie=&oe=#q=regex+guid+test+c-sharp

5) Maintain a list of your classes and test for IndexOf